# phpPgAdmin and XAMPP problem

Tags: php, postgresql, xampp

I would like to use phpPgAdmin 4.2.3 in combination with XAMPP 1.7.3 and postgresql-8.4.4.

When I finally managed to get all the files edited in order to run phpPgAdmin and postgresql-8.4.4 all I have after visiting mz http://127.0.0.1/phppgadmin/ is:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\Programs\xampp\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php on line 344

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at D:\Programy\xampp\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php:344) in D:\Programs\xampp\phpPgAdmin\libraries\lib.inc.php on line 56

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\Programy\xampp\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php:344) in D:\Programs\xampp\phpPgAdmin\libraries\lib.inc.php on line 56

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\Programs\xampp\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php:344) in D:\Programs\xampp\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php on line 361
```

My error_reporting in php.ini looks like this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I tried this too:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED)
```

Why it's still not working? Is there maybe some other piece of software with Apache and Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use phpPgAdmin version 5.0 ? The older versions are for PHP version 4.x and will have problems with the latest PHP versions.

Comment: Thanks :D. Was easier then I thought :P.